# Agregar iconos de + y - a cada elemento del nav si tienen elementos

Tags: html, css, uikit-3

Hola estoy haciendo un menu utilizando el framework de css UIkit en su versión 3, quiero hacer un menu utilizando los sub-nav, pero no consigo cambiar el icono del subnav predeterminando de flecha por uno de suma si esta abierto y otro de resta si esta cerrado.
Dejo el link del codepen si alguno tiene la respuesta.

[Link codepen](https://codepen.io/pancho-bolatti/pen/qBmdjqW)

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo manejarlo por estilos, en la parte de Productos quitaria el icono y lo cambiaria asi

```html
<a href="#">Productos<span uk-icon="icon: triangle-down"></span></a>

<a href="#">Productos<span class="drop-icon"></span></a>
```

Entonces con el css puedes ponerle un icono que responda a los cambios de abierto y cerrado

```css
.drop-icon:before {
  content: "\002B";
}

.uk-open .drop-icon:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
```